# HP ProBook 440 G7 - Not recognizing HDMI devices

Tags: hdmi

I didn't touch my laptop but my HDMI port started to not recognize devices, I have an HDMI to USB-C adaptor and that was working fine.

I make some tests from the BIOS and everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade the version of the BIOS-System Firmware to 01.11.00 Rev.A

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-440-g7-notebook-pc/29090063
[image]